# How to map over an GET method response with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, odata

This code returns:
TypeError: data.map is not a function, at Orders.js:18

I import this component to my `app.js` and use it to get data from OData servers.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export default class Orders extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        this.state = {
            Orders: []
        };
    }
    getOrdersData() {
        axios
            .get(`Orders`, {})
            .then(res => {
                const data = res.data
                console.log(data)
                const Orders = data.map(u =>
                    <div>
                    <p>{u.CustomerId}</p>
                    
                    </div>
                    )

                    this.setState({
                        Orders
                    })

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })

    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.getOrdersData()
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.Orders}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**the returned response looks something like this on the console:**

```
{d: {…}}
d:
results: Array(200)
[0 … 99]
0:
Customer: {__deferred: {…}}
CustomerID: "DOGA"
Employee: {__deferred: {…}}
EmployeeID: 2
Freight: "56.234"
OrderDate: "/Date(836438400000)/"
OrderID: 12345
Order_Details: {__deferred: {…}}
RequiredDate: "/Date(838857600000)/"
```

I want to create a table and map those results by their orderId on a table.

**This is a piece of the response from API:**

```
{
"d" : {
"results": [
{
"__metadata": {
"uri": "https://services.odata.org/V2/northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders(10248)", "type": "NorthwindModel.Order"
}, "OrderID": 10248, "CustomerID": "VINET", "EmployeeID": 5, "OrderDate": "\/Date(836438400000)\/", "RequiredDate": "\/Date(838857600000)\/", "ShippedDate": "\/Date(837475200000)\/", "ShipVia": 3, "Freight": "32.3800", "ShipName": "Vins et alcools Chevalier", "ShipAddress": "59 rue de l'Abbaye", "ShipCity": "Reims", "ShipRegion": null, "ShipPostalCode": "51100", "ShipCountry": "France", "Customer": {
"__deferred": {
"uri": "https://services.odata.org/V2/northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders(10248)/Customer"
}
}, "Employee": {
"__deferred": {
"uri": "https://services.odata.org/V2/northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders(10248)/Employee"
}
}, "Order_Details": {
"__deferred": {
"uri": "https://services.odata.org/V2/northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders(10248)/Order_Details"
}
}, "Shipper": {
"__deferred": {
"uri": "https://services.odata.org/V2/northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders(10248)/Shipper"
}
}
}, {
```

Comment: Look at the log of `data`: it has a `d` property, which itself apparently has a `results` property. You need to get the correct data to iterate over before iterating over it.

Comment: Could you please show whats the response that comes from this API? If you go to the Network tab on the Dev Tools, you will be able to see the response from that request call. It seems you are reading the wrong property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are trying to map over an object.

[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)is an array method.

maybe you want to loop over the `results` array (`data.results`)?

Comment: Hello @shai_sharakanski I tried to change `const data = res.data` to `const data = res.data.results` but that also give an error of **Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**. Since I am a beginner can you give an example please.

Comment: @selcuky Sure, can you add a Codesandbox or a screenshot of the console?

Comment: sure here this is the  [link](https://i.imgur.com/a0Ecn4x.png)

Comment: @selcuky Please add a new image with the log of `res.data` and not `res.data.results`.

Comment: this is the second with `res.data` @shai_sharakanski. [link](https://imgur.com/a/0qoLswS)

Comment: @selcuky Try this: `res.data.d.results.map()`, If it won't work, please add another image and open the object in the console by clicking the small arrow or add a Codesandbox.